# User defined Plug-in in Audacity

Tags: c++, audacity

I have developed an algorithm for Pitch/Time scaling for speech signals .
I want to create a plug- in for it in Audacity .For time being I want to create it locally , plug-in only system.How do I do it ?Could someone help me out ?
I have its .cpp file existing .Is there any way I could fork it into Audacity and create plugin using it .

Algorithm:
In my algorithm for time scaling , Upon running I need to enter a factor between 0.5 - 2 . 0.5 factor would scale down the speech signal and play the signal at a slow rate while factor 2 would would speed up the speech signal .In Pitch scaling : Similarly enter the factor between 0.5 -2 , 0.5 would change the pitch to a male voice (more base ) while factor 2 would result in a higher pitch resembling a female voice .The only input to my code is a input speech signal and a scale factor.

My .cpp code depends on two external libraries :armadillo and libsndfile 
g++ TSM.cpp armadillo libsndfile -o tsm ( How I need to compile )

Hoping for your reply .
Hoping to find a solution to my problem

Comment: see this: https://github.com/audacity

Comment: Audacity supports LADSPA, LV2 and VST plugins.